# SSLError bad handshake ECONNRESET + TIMEOUT on azure portal only on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: azure, ubuntu, ssl, timeout, azureportal

When I try to access storage account or function app I get TIMEOUT on request for: https://management.azure.com/batch?api-version=2015-11-01

It works on windows, only fails when I use Chrome/FF/Brave on ubuntu.

[screenshot - error I get on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSN7U.png)

On firefox I get warning before timeout:
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://management.azure.com/batch?api-version=2015-11-01. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)`

I am not behind any proxy, ad block turned off, no cors extensions, no hope.

Comment: I found out, that I have problem with management.azure.com - even when I try to make `az login`
I get: `urllib3.connectionpool : Starting new HTTPS connection (1): management.azure.com:443
urllib3.util.retry : Incremented Retry for (url='/tenants?api-version=2016-06-01'): Retry(total=3, connect=4, read=4, redirect=None, status=None)
urllib3.connectionpool : Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=4, read=4, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')",),)': /tenants?api-version=2016-06-01`

Comment: You can add an answer to describe the reason and the solution to your question, it would help other communities who searching it.